# March 2019 Photo competition. Bus stops +

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

For March 2019 the theme for the Travel Stack Exchange photo competition will be **Bus stops** and other places where people start (or finish) communal travel.

Inspiration: Bus and train stations, car share parking areas, hitch hikers in a line on the side of a road, ferry landing areas, airports.
So **not** buses, train, planes and ferries themselves, it is where you start (or end) the travel. The vehicles for travel may be included in the photo, but they **have to be at a stop.**

Rules:

- 1 photo per answer.
- You may submit more than 1 answer per user. But keep it to no more than 3 posts.
- Try and keep it non offensive.
- **All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and the date the photo was taken.**
- The photo has to be taken by the user* who posted it and taken in the time frame given in the description for that month's photo.
  (*Or one of a two people team, give credit to the actual person who took the photo, nick names are acceptable.)
- Remember we are 'Travel' stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)

The next rules changes per month, the subject of the picture and its 'when it was taken'.

For the month of March I would like to set the rules:

- The photo can have been taken anytime.
- The subject of the photo is Bus stops and other places where people start (or finish) communal travel.
- The photo should not be of people, as such, but it is rather likely that one or more will be in the picture. If so, either in such a way you can not recognize them or you should have permission to post their photo online. It is up to the person posting the photo to make sure that it is up to the laws of the country where the picture was taken.
- No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of March 2019, voting will run till midnight, the last seconds of March 2019* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

I am looking forward to your photos.

User Tor-Einar Jarnbjo has won the March competition, with a few votes on the number two, fkraiem.

User hippietrail has won the virtual prize, he wins the virtual prize, it would have been a completely unorganized foot travel to Rome, but as he mentioned the 'magic words' FAKE NEWS, it will metamorph into a completely unorganized foot travel to the holy place of his choice. Of course no travel cost included nor help given.

Comment: I find the question way too broad, ask for a bus stop or a railway station or airport etc, but not for any of them.

Comment: @PeterHandorf As many people live in areas where bus stops and/or train stations do not exist, making the question narrow would exclude several or even most of our users. My intention is to allow everybody to join in. Best post this kind of comment when the competition is announced or at least before the month has started, as then we can do something about it. Not likely I would have this month, nor the next.

Comment: I agree, I should have posted this earlier. Areas with no bus stops?, yes I can think of a few remote places, but I don't think many of our users live there. And you don't have to live somewhere to take a photo of something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

Spikkestad stasjon, Norway, December 29th, 2016

Comment: Just like the geometry of a snowflake, everything in this picture is made of simple geometric shapes: the perfectly straight railway tracks, the catenaries of the overhead electric lines and the triangles of their support structures; the evenly spaced perpendicular lights and the signals. Stark, yet mesmerizing. Love it.

Comment: I'll back @undercat 's comments - in all seriousness, the quality and lines of this image, it's textbook! Picture perfect!

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Hitachinai station, Japan, 11 January, 2016.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Moscow has some of the  most beautiful underground stations in the world.

**Mayakovskaya** Metro Station, Moscow, Russia. 16 June 2018.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, this is [Mayakovskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayakovskaya_%28Moscow_Metro%29) on the green line, and is probably my favourite in the Metro :)

Answer (score 10):

[image: Bottroper Straße U-bahn station]

> Bottroper Straße U-Bahn station

This photo was taken on Feb 02, 2018 at Bottroper Straße U-Bahn station, when I was in Stuttgart, Germany.

Thanks to Google Photos app, the photo's colours are vibrant :)

Answer (score 10):

[image: bus stop in Dubai]

A fully air conditioned bus stop in Dubai, UAE. Taken January 15th 2015. I think in winter the AC was not actually used.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Seattle Bus Tunnel]

A bus stop in the Seattle bus tunnel, somewhere below downtown Seattle WA. 
I still haven't seen a proper bus tunnel like this anywhere else in the world. Photo was taken September 17th 2008.

Comment: I love that station! So unique!

Answer (score 10):

[image]

A cheery parking lot(автостоянка) sign amidst a vast expanse of pristine green hills, with no cars or roads around for at least one mile. The sign is clearly well tended. Its very existence and purpose are truly an enigma.

Might be a metaphor for something. Also might be the best kind of a parking lot I've ever seen.

([Pereslavl-Zalesskiy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pereslavl-Zalessky), Russia, September 2018)

Comment: "They paved paradise and put up a parking lot"?

Answer (score 9):

[image: Frankfurt main station]

Frankfurt main station, Germany.

Photo taken on 11th of Mai 2017

Answer (score 8):

[image: A bus stop sign which is quite dirty]
Taken 2 January 2019, in Bishops Cannings, Wiltshire, UK.

I knew I was likely to have a 'bus stop' photo competition some day, so when I saw this rather weathered sign I knew what I was going to send in for that competition.

There is a shelter with readable information near.

Answer (score 8):

Space Shuttle Discovery, at Kennedy Space Center's launch pads, November 2010.

[image]

Comment: Now that’s a nice bus stop. +1

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This is an old faded cable car stop sign (纜車站) found at the [intersection of Mason and Filbert](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.8009202,-122.4126447,3a,58.5y,156.96h,91.12t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s3Eas6AyOMl4ppdYOUs8jYA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192) in San Francisco, CA. Unlike all other signs I've seen in the Bay area, it doesn't have an English counterpart (if you don't count the hastily attached stop ID sticker). Despite its old age, the cable cars honor it fully and will always gracefully stop to pay their respects. (May 2016)

Comment: I like the story!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Train station at La Pobla de Segur, Spain. We took this train to Lleida shortly after this photo was taken. 27 July 2004.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[Park Pobedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Pobedy_(Moscow_Metro)) Metro Station, Moscow, Russia. 16 June 2018

> **Park Pobedy** (Russian: Парк Победы – Victory Park) is a station of the Moscow Metro in the city's Dorogomilovo District. It is on two lines: the Arbatsko–Pokrovskaya line and the Kalininsko–Solntsevskaya line. At 84 metres (276 ft) underground, according to the official figures, it is the deepest metro station in Moscow and one of the deepest in the world (after Kiev Metro's Arsenalna, Chongqing Rail Transit's Hongtudi Station and Saint Petersburg Metro's Admiralteyskaya).

**Fun Tip:** If you focus on the escalator for a few seconds it will start to look like a travelator! Try it. A really long escalator on one of the deepest underground stations suddenly looks like there is zero depth!

Answer (score 7):

[image]

I clicked this while I was standing by a railtrack on a station, waiting for my train. Its a rural station with only a few trains halting at it, watching the trains and experiment different camera mode has been my hobby.

I hope the guy sitting in the door of the train passing by doesn't mind me posting this picture online. :-)

Place: Kamshet Railway Station, Maharashtra, India.
Date: February 2017.

Answer (score 7):

I captured this bus stop near Viñales, Cuba on the 7th of March, 2019. I tried to get a stop with no people but it was a busy day that day and every stop was full of people!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Little old village bus stop near Taichung, Taiwan]

A little old bus shelter (候車亭) in Nanliao Village (南寮裏), just outside Taichung, Taiwan.

Taken during my explorations today, March 18 2019.

Answer (score 7):

Somewhere in the area around Kiruna, Sweden:

[image: Somewhere in the area around Kiruna]

See also [this SE answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/93015/2509).

Answer (score 6):

[image: a bus parked outside a small building]
Taken 10 March 2016, in Honfleur France, by my good friend Marijke, when she and I were traveling together.
The building you see is the Gare routière de Honfleur, which is a bus station rather than just a stop. Still most services I have seen there were of the 'local' kind, stopping in almost every village on its route even when running for two or three hours.

Answer (score 6):

This photo was taken by me following breakfast, at Adelaide Railway Station, South Australia on 21 June (mid winter there) 2013.  As can be seen from the sign on the table, it was taken from just past Jasper's cafe.  The morning sunlight and the lights saturated the shot, but you get a glimpse of the ceiling, which is magnificent.  I have an extra shot of just the ceiling, but that would require a different entry.

.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Sydney international airport, taken from QF922 from SYD to CNS on February 28th.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Dunedin Railway Station]

Dunedin Railway Station, South Island New Zealand.  If you look closely, the photo also captures the bus stop in front of the station. Taken by myself on 27 October 2013.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61483/101

Answer (score 6):

[image]

This is a panoramic view of the Mumbai International Airport.
Date: November 2017.

Answer (score 5):

This picture was taken in Beijing, May 2013. If I remember correctly is it the bus stop behind the Dongzhimen metro station. A bus from this station brought me to Mutianyu (Great Wall)
[image: Dongzhimen bus station]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

ِAn actual landing/take-off spot for helicopters in an uninhabited island in the Dominican Republic. Taken sometime in 2017.

Comment: Just some well-ment advice: If you have problems holding the camera straight, you can rotate the image later in any arbitrary image processing software. Your image is tilting to the left. When you are already working on the picture, you could also have cropped away the half arm, which is protruding into the image on the right side :-)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I guess I am blessed for not being a photographer... man you saw all that wrong in a photo I thought was perfect :D

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Charing Cross station, London, 9 April 2009.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Longtail boat on Tonsai Beach, Krabi, Thailand. The evening sun is illuminating the climbing crag "Fire Wall" in the background.

Picture taken by me in December 2012 and modified for brightness, contrast and to reduce file size.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Circular Quay Ferry Terminal, Sydney, Tuesday Feb 26.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering: the cruise ship in the back left is the Royal Caribbean Ovation of the Seas.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Komsomolskaya Metro Station, Moscow, Russia. 16 June 2018.

Comment: Thanks for posting your great photos. (But please note, there is a request not to post more than 3, no need to delete any but please no more extra.)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I clicked this while I was standing by a railtrack on a station, waiting for my train. Experiment different camera mode have been my hobby. This a kind of a failed attempt to capture a fast passing railway with the camera in a long exposure mode.

Date: January 2017.
Place: Lonwala Railway Station, Maharastra, India.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Zürich Hauptbahnhof, Switzerland.]

This is Zürich Hauptbahnhof, the largest railway station in Switzerland.

Photo Taken on: May 12, 2018

Answer (score 4):

[image: a ferry with cars driving off]
The ferry leaving from Fynshav Denmark.
Either the ferry to Ærø, or to Fyn, taken while I was on my way to Ærøskøbing, where there was a sailing and knot tying event.
Taken on 13 July 2017.

Answer (score 4):

### Hellemobotn/Vuodnabahta, 23 September 2013

[image: Hellemobotn/Vuodnabahta, 23 September 2013]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Chinese temple at night with pink bus stop sign in front]
Pink bus stop sign in front of a temple at night, Changhua (彰化) Taiwan.
Taken two nights ago.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

DXB, Emirates and A380 are Synonymous with each other!

15 June 2018

<sub>Fun Fact: There are total 6 A380s partially visible in this picture if you zoom close enough.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[image: Blurry bus stop sign with UFO parked on the other side of the highway]
Bus stop across the road from spaceport with flying saucer waiting. Taken while hitchhiking in southern Taiwan a few days ago.

Comment: There are rumours that the flying saucer is actually just a monument to mark the Tropic of Cancer. That's obviously FAKE NEWS!

Comment: You win the virtual prize, it would have been a completely unorganized foot travel to Rome, but as you mentioned the 'magic words' FAKE NEWS, it will metamorph into a completely unorganized foot travel to the holy place of your choice. Of course no travel cost included nor help given.